# What's the @ operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the C++ reference page [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) it has a table of operators, but I don't understand what the `operator@` is. For example:

`@a     (a).operator@ ( )   operator@ (a)   !std::cin calls std::cin.operator!()`

However there's no such operator in the language. What does it mean?

Comment: Since it is not a valid C++ operator seems It is a placeholder for actual operators.

Comment: Did you see the examples ?

Comment: It is a symbol that represents an operator

Comment: They write operator@ as a shorthand for all possible operators: (operator!, operator++. operator<<. etc.. etc..)

Comment: Wow, that is one confusing bit of documentation.  I don't blame you for not understanding it right away.

Comment: @JohnZwinck added a brief explanatory note, better?

Comment: @Cubbi: hey thanks, that's helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@` is not a valid C++ operator and It is used here as a *placeholder* for actual operators.
In short, it can be replaced by any of the actual C++ operators and the statement should hold good for that particular operator.

Comment: @user4176466: The path to knowing things naturally flows through a phase of not knowing them. So no need to feel bad about it.

Answer (score 7):

The cppreference page as well as the C++ standard treat the `@` character as a placeholder for real operators. It is not used to code.